# Multiple terms tax query, modify by it's parent category with AND-OR operator , Multiselect relation logic

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building an online shop with Wordpress - Woocommerce and facing on a issue with categories product filtering

My Products Categories looks like this:

- Brand

  Nike

  Adidas

  Rebook

  Puma
- Gender

  Male

  Female
- Type of product

  Shoes

  Clothes

  Accessories

If I select Brand:Nike and Gender:Male, it shows me not only products of Nike with Gender:Male but other brands with gender male also...

Here is what I want to do: If I select Nike, Adidas brands and gender male I want to show only products with nike or adidas brands and gender nike, PS.From some researches I've made on url params is product_cat=nike,adidas -> is like OR if I change manually to product_cat=nike+adidas -> is like AND,

I want to make like hirearchial groups of categories like this to filter product_cat=nike,adidas+male

products are filtered dynamically with AJAX

Do you have any clue or piece of code that I can modify (NOT PLUGIN) to do it? without custom taxonomies!?

Thanks

**UPDATED:**

Code I tried:

```
   function modify_tax_query( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('s'), 'product_cat');
    if ( $term && !is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => array($term->slug),
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        ),
        );
        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $tax_query;
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $query->tax_query->queries;
        $query->set('tax_query', $query->tax_query->queries);
     }
}}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_tax_query', 1 );
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, I've seen that you commented yesterday also but I deleted question because I thinked that I've found solution but I dont.

Comment: Here is what I tried

Comment: function modify_tax_querey( $query ) {
if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('s'), 'product_cat');
    if ( $term && !is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
        $tax_query = array(
   'relation' => 'AND',
   array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => array($term->slug),
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
        ),
  );
        $query->tax_query->queries[] = $tax_query;
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = $query->tax_query->queries;

Comment: $query->set('tax_query', $query->tax_query->queries);
     }
}}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_tax_querey', 1 );

Comment: Please edit your question add come code there not in the comments.

Comment: when product_cat is called to modify query with relation AND but it didn't work. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I edited it